# Making passing grade colum using `NaN` variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to map a certain data set into certain passing criteria with elaborate `NaN`, for example M 3 10+ will be valued `1` if `M 3` value at least  `10`, value `0` for valued less than `0` and valued `NaN` if `M3` is `NaN`

Here's my data

```
customer_id        M 1        M 2       M 3       M 4                  
1                    3          5         5        10          
2                    3          5         15      NaN       
3                    3          15        23      NaN
```

Here's my expected uotput

```
customer_id          M 3 10+    M 3 20+    M 4 10+    M 4 20+                
1                          0         0          1           0
2                          1         0        NaN         NaN 
3                          1         1        NaN         NaN
```

I try `df.loc[(df['M3 >= 10] , 'M3 10+'] = 1` but its only resulting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `product` for all combinations of columns with values for test and for new columns use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
cols = ['M 3','M 4']
vals = [10, 20]

from  itertools import product

for c, v in product(cols, vals):
    df[f'{c} {v}+'] = np.select([df[c] < v, df[c] >= v], [0, 1], np.nan)
print (df)
   customer_id  M 1  M 2  M 3   M 4  M 3 10+  M 3 20+  M 4 10+  M 4 20+
0            1    3    5    5  10.0      0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0
1            1    3    5   15   NaN      1.0      0.0      NaN      NaN
2            1    3   15   23   NaN      1.0      1.0      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a syntax error is because there is an unclosed quote and an unclosed bracket in your statement.

It should be

```py
df.loc[(df['M 3'] >= 10) , 'M3 10+'] = 1
```